# Disable autocommit for DB2 connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: db2, oracle-sql-developer

I am connecting to the DB2 database using oracle SQL developer, but automatically it is committing, i checked in the advanced menu the auto commit feature is turned off. I am confused now, can someone help me in switching off auto commit.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether auto-commit is really off (or if it's a glitch in the gui), by (for example):

```
1. create table T (x int);
2. rollback;
3. select * from t;   -- should result in an error
```

Comment: No error in selecting data

Comment: Then autocommit is on regardless of what the gui says

Comment: What happens if you enable auto-commit, and then disable it again?